# One general context menu

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I have one general context menu and for example 4 buttons and 4 textboxes - when I click on any of these buttons the context menu is opened and when I click on some items I would like to send this item to textbox, which was between button - I need to send some identificator to context menu to know which button open it and then to know where to send selected item. 
How can I do that? 
I am using c#
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.ActiveControl` will give you the button that has the focus.  You can put the identifier in the `Tag` property of each button.  This way, `this.ActiveControl.Tag` will give you the information you need.